# Haskell Programmatically/Dynamically Define Functions

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm looking for a way to dynamically define functions in Haskell, or for Haskell's idiomatic equivilent of which I'm clearly not aware.

The scenario is as follows: I have a `tagWithAttrs` function that generates new functions based on the provided `String` argument. The definition looks something like this:

```
tagWithAttrs :: String -> ([(String, String)] -> [String] -> String)
tagWithAttrs tagName = [...]  -- Implementation ommited to save room.

h1 :: [(String, String)] -> [String] -> String
h1 = tagWithAttrs "h1"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ h1 [("id", "abc"), ("class", "def")] ["A H1 Test"]

-- Should display '<h1 id="abc" class="def">A H1 Test</h1>'.
```

So far so good. But the line in which I assign `h1` is one of many, since I'd have to do that for every single HTML tag I'm defining. In Python, I'd loop over a list of the HTML tag names, inserting each respective result from `tag_with_attrs` into the dictionary returned by `globals()`. In short, I'd be inserting new entries into the symbol table dynamically.

What is the Haskell equivilent of this idiom?

*Btw, I'm fully aware that I'm duplicating the work of many existing libraries that already do HTML tags. I'm doing this for a toy project, nothing more :)*

EDIT: Some posted solutions are suggesting mechanisms that still rely on defining the *end result* tag functions one-by-one. This violates DRY, else I would have just done it how I was doing it. It's that DRY violation that I'm trying to side-step.

Comment: This doesn't require dynamic function definition, just first class functions.

Comment: I would love to know how to do this using higher order functions, given that I'd much prefer that to meta-compilation trickery. But I want the results as simple as a function call, not looking up some function in a data structure.

Comment: To clarify, the only way of doing it with straight functions would be by defining one for every single tag, or by looking up the one I want in a data structure. The former is verbose for the code definition, the latter for code usage. I'm looking for a way that I don't know of, that seems to be TH atm.

Comment: Don't try to shoehorn another languages' solution to this problem into Haskell; this can be done cleanly without any metaprogramming, as Don and Ertes mention, and learning how to do so will probably teach you much more about Haskell and functional programming than Template Haskell ever could.

Comment: I know. That is precisely why I'm asking for such a solution that doesn't violate DRY or force data-structure lookups on every use. I'm aware that my current idea isn't idiomatic Haskell, and nor is TH. But being idiomatic isn't useful if it's horribly verbose. I'd assumed skilled Haskell coders knew an idiomatic solution that didn't violate DRY. That's what I want :)

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest rewriting the question to be more clear about what you need and why you need it; instead of describing how you solved the problem in another language, describe what the original problem was and its context.

Comment: OK, more abstractly, I want to define a tag generator for every tag in the HTML standard, without defining every single tag seperately. Each tag is **currently** generated by a function-returning function recieving a string. How do you think I should approach it instead?

Comment: Although I'd probably use a code-generation approach myself, it's a little frustrating to see continual suggestions that don't really solve the questioner's problem.  The obvious non-TH way to do this is to create a data type `data HtmlTag = H1 | H2 | H3 deriving (Eq, Show)`, then build a map (as ertes suggests) with `HtmlTag` as keys using the Show instance and your existing `tagWithAttrs`.  Then create a new function `tag :: HtmlTag -> [(String,String)] -> [String] -> String` that looks up the tag in the map, which you would use as `putStrLn $ tag H1 ...`.  Which is still a bit more verbose.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't need a map then, `tag = tagWithAttrs . show`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell is statically typed, which means that all symbols must be type-checked at compile time. So that means you can't add entries into the symbol table at runtime.

What you want is meta-programming. Where code runs at **compile time** to generate other code (that you naturally and rightly feel lazy to type). That implies something like a macro system .

Haskell does not have macros, but there is template Haskell:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell

As with macros, the idea is that you write a function that generates an
AST. The meta-function takes the name of the function you want to use (in your 
case, `div`, `ul`, `li` etc) and generates the AST of a functional with that name.

A bit overkill, but if you really want to do it this is a relatively simple tutorial:
http://playingwithpointers.com/archives/615

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd considered TH before, but thought that I was resorting to it was because I was using the wrong mindset for the problem in Haskell. I'll probably end up using TH, but I wonder how something like this is done without it. How would such a design be done without too much duplication and also without violating the type-system or using compile-time mutations?

Comment: The important thing is that it can't be done without resorting to something like TH. Proof by contradiction: if we assume it can, then there exists some code which makes an association with a function name `f` and say, a lambda. Now `f` must **always** pass type-checking; i.e., the code that generates it must **always** succeed, something that cannot be guaranteed at compile time.

Comment: After considering, I guess TH seems to be the solution for what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This can be done easily with some [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Monad (forM)
import Language.Haskell.TH

tagWithAttrs :: String -> ([(String, String)] -> [String] -> String)
tagWithAttrs tagName = undefined

$(forM ["h1", "h2", "h3"] $ \tag ->
   valD (varP (mkName tag)) (normalB [| tagWithAttrs $(stringE tag) |]) [])

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ h1 [("id", "abc"), ("class", "def")] ["A H1 Test"]
```

This generates declarations `h1 = tagWithAttrs "h1"`, `h2 = tagWithAttrs "h2"`, `h3 = tagWithAttrs "h3"`, and so on. To add more, just add them to the list.

The code is a bit ugly since it's not possible to splice patterns in TH. Otherwise, we would have been able to write something like `[d| $(mkName tag) = tagWithAttrs $(stringE tag) |]`. Instead, we have to manually construct the declaration using TH combinators.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the usage example, it'll come in handy given that TH is the route I decided to go down.

Answer (score 6):

Well, as you know Haskell is curried and functions are first class, so you really don't need any magic to do that.  Just recognize that you can do stuff like:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Text (Text)

type TagName = Text
type TagWithAttrs = Map TagName ([(String, String)] -> [String] -> String)

tagFuncs :: TagWithAttrs
tagFuncs =
    M.fromList $
    ("h1", \xs ys -> zs) :
    ("h2", \xs ys -> zs) :
    {- ... -}
    []

tagWithAttrs :: TagName -> [(String, String)] -> [String] -> String
tagWithAttrs = flip M.lookup tagFuncs
```

This is all regular efficient Haskell.  Note: You may be tempted to define `tagFuncs` as a local value to `tagWithAttrs` by using a `where` clause.  While this can make your code more beautiful it will also result in the map to be regenerated for each invocation of `tagWithAttrs`.

To dynamically insert things into the map you can make the map an argument of `tagWithAttrs` instead of a top level map.  Another alternative is to use a concurrent variable like an `MVar` or (probably better) a `TVar`.

Comment: So there's a map which gets looked up by the specified string when producing tag functions, returning the respective function for each. For `h1`, it's defined as an entry in the map. For `h2` you defined it as an entry in a map. For `h3`... it's the exact same problem as the original code. It's repeating itself over an over again. I don't see how the intermediate map betters the design over the OP, but perhaps not seeing it is due to me missing something.

You'd still have to define a `tagFuncs` entry for every single tag right? So the map hasn't solved anything.

Answer (score 4):

I think what I would do would be to define a data type for tags:

```
data Tag = H1 | H2 | H3 ...
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
```

This is your single point of definition for all the tags that there are.

Then define a function that maps `Tag` values to the appropriate function:

```
tag :: Tag -> [(String, String)] -> [String] -> String
tag = tagWithAttrs . show
```

And then where you want to call `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, you instead call `tag H1`, `tag H2`, `tag H3`, etc.

Note that this is **identical** in verbosity to if you had defined functions `tag_h1`, `tag_h2`, `tag_h3`, etc; effectively you've just got slightly longer names (which happen to include a space). To me this is the ideal combination of DRY and "say what you mean". `h1` doesn't seem like a function to me anyway; I'd actually much rather think that I was working with one function on a number of data items than that I had a giant set of functions.

If I was then unsatisfied with the speed of this (because the compiler probably won't optimize away all of the `tagWithAttrs` calls away) ***and*** I had determined that this was the "lowest hanging fruit" to speed up my application, I would look at memoizing `tagWithAttrs` or `tag`, but internally so as to keep the same interface. One quick possibility: pre-populate a map with all tags; you can use the `Enum` and `Bounded` instance to do this without explicitly re-listing all the tags (this is something you couldn't do with tags represented by functions or by strings). A side benefit of non-strict evaluation is that this will probably result in `tagWithAttrs` being evaluated exactly once for each tag that is actually used.

That would still leave a data-structure lookup on each `tag` call (unless the compiler is clever enough to optimise them away, which is not impossible). I doubt that would be the most significant performance bottleneck unless you've done some heavy optimisation of the rest of your program. To do all the lookups at compile time (without relying on the optimiser), I think you do need Template Haskell. I probably wouldn't go that far in this case, just because I sincerely doubt I would need it to go any faster (and I have *way* more available compute-time than me-time). But even if I was using Template Haskell to get the lookups done at compile-time I would prefer to *not* make it look like a separate top-level function for each tag; I just find "tags and a function that knows how to render tags" to be a more natural and flexible approach than "tags, which can be called to render themselves".

Comment: I like this solution. Using types over code-generation certainly /seems/ like more idiomatic Haskell to me. And the extra verbosity isn't really that much, given that listing a type constructor each tag is much less typing than assigning a function to a value named after each tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple code generator, input the list of tags you want, include the output as a module.